# How to Create a MsWord TOC without automation?

Tags: reporting-services, ms-word, reporting, tableofcontents

I'm using Aspose.Words to construct a Word Document programmatically (C#) on a server.  The dynamically generated documents can be imported by clients via a web interface.  Everything is great except I'm unable to generate a TOC.  I've already exhausted my options with Aspose.  Updating TOC fields is simply not a feature that Aspose currently supports.  So... I'm open to any other viable solution even if it involves other third-party components.  Automation has been ruled out because the Word Document is constructed on the server-side and Microsoft does not recommend using Automation on servers.

Can anyone suggest a solution?  The optimal solution would be simply to be able to programmatically do a TOC Field Update.  The solution cannot require installation of Word on the server.  Are there any server-side reporting components that support this feature?

If a simple TOC Field Update solution is not available, then the next best thing would probably be the ability to programmatically construct a TOC by inspecting the Word document and extracting page numbers.

All ideas and input are welcome.  I need a solution very soon.

Thanks,

Ed

Comment: are you using wordML to build this?  or the word.document object?

Comment: I'm not using wordML, I'm using Aspose's Document Object Model.  But, if there's a reasonable way to build a TOC using WordML, I'm opening to using it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net-and-java/aspose.words.documentbuilder.inserttableofcontents.html

BUt i can't find a way to generate it automatically without using F9 key in MS Word...

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem.  Having the user have to hit F9 is not acceptable, especially if one offers other output formats like PDF.  I got around the problem by adding bookmarks to each chapter I wanted to see on the TOC and then manually building a table using the bookmarks as references.  it's not a perfect solution but it's OK for now.  I think Aspose will add support for TOC fields in 2010.